# Google map not displayed in my android application now it displayed before two days

Tags: android

I developed apps with google map.I got map key i got google map in my application two days before .I did nt change anything but now i did not get the google map only show boxes .The logcat show **couldn't get connection factory client error**.I searched this error but i can't get clear ans as well as map .So plz anyone help me to solve this problem.

Thanks ,
Lakshmanan

Answer (score 0):

I've had that error appearing as well, so please check the following :

- Your API Key has been correctly generated (sadly, no tool to check for that) (see [this tutorial](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android))
- You have a `INTERNET` permission in your manifest, within the `<manifest>` tag
- You have a `uses-library` within the `<application>` tag
- You start the emulator with a Google Maps API Target
- You have internet (3G display) within the emulator

Just a small checklist, hope this helps !